# Confusion between true negatives and false positives (double negation?!)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, false-discovery-rate, signal-detection, type-i-and-ii-errors

Given the below term definitions

[image]

..my question is: why is the logical negation (opposite) of a false negative not a true negative? This would imply **1-α=β**, which does not have to be the case.

And same for positives: I'd have thought that what is left after counting the false positives is the true positives. In other words, that one minus the false positive rate, i.e. 1-α, is is the true positive rate, which is 1-β. This would imply **α=β**, which is (again) not necessarily true!

Can anyone help clear the confusion?

Comment: This is not easy to explain.  You have to see that in part of this you are looking at the null hypothesis.  That is where alpha comes in.  Beta is considered the power of the test under a specific alternative.  1- alpha deals with not rejecting the null hypothesis while 1-beta represent the probability of not rejecting when the specific alternative is "true".

Comment: Specificity deals with the null hypothesis and sensitivity with the alternative. So alpha does not equal beta.

Comment: I wonder what you mean by "logical negation."  A false negative, fully spelled out, is a condition where *the null hypothesis is true* **and** *the null is not rejected.*  According to the propositional calculus, then, its negation is *the null hypothesis is false* **or** *the null is rejected.* How do you conclude $1-\alpha=\beta$ from that?

Comment: @whuber Better to just say the null is not rejected.  In statistics nothing is certain.

Comment: @Michael Isn't that exactly what I wrote?

Comment: I assumed that "1-" is the right way to express the negation of a certain probability, i.e. if the chance of a black/white ball to be white is P, then the chance of it being black is 1-P. Is this is not correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The terms 'postive' and 'negative' are used with respect to underlying null ($H_0$) and alternate ($H_1$) hypotheses. Both hypotheses specify how your test statistic should be distributed, given that they are correct.

If the $H_0$ is correct, the test statistic will be distributed according to the null distribution, and it will have a probability of $\alpha$ of falling in the rejection region. I.e. with probability $\alpha$ you will reject the null hypothesis even if it is true - this is the **False Positive Rate**. Conversely, there is $1-\alpha$ probability of failing to reject the null hypothesis; this is the **True Negative Rate** (since the null hypothesis is true here, you should not reject it).

Now consider that $H_0$ is false, and $H_1$ is true. Now the test statistic is distributed according to the alternate distribution. With probability $\beta$, the test statistic will fall outside the rejection region. This is the **False Negative Rate**, since you failed to reject $H_0$ even when it was false. Conversely, with probability $1-\beta$ you correctly reject the null hypothesis, hence it is called the **True Positive Rate**.

I found the following image which might be helpful in understanding (source: [probabilitycourse.com, chapter 8](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter8/8_4_2_general_setting_definitions.php)).

[image: Alpha and Beta]

Here $X$ is the test statistic. The null hypothesis is rejected if $X>c$. Following from the above discussion, we can express $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as these conditional probabilities.

$$\alpha = p(X>c|H_0) \implies 1-\alpha = p(X<c|H_0)$$

$$\beta = p(X<c|H_1) \implies 1-\beta = p(X>c|H_1)$$

Comment: +1 Nicely done.  Looks like a textbook answer. I like to explain that there really is a power function where beta increases as the mean separation between the null and alternative widens as would be the case in your picture if we change the alternative to N(2, 9).

Comment: Thanks! Your answer clarified why the "opposite" (as I called it; not the best term probably; anyway, meaning "1-") of the False Positive Rate is in fact the True Negative Rate, which leaves me with no further questions.

Comment: It's as if both terms in each rate (*False*_*Positive* & *True*_*Negative*) need to be "negated".

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to explain some more: Suppose the patient is sick and given a test - the test can result either in a true positive outcome or in a false negative outcome, and so these two probabilities (1-beta and beta, respectively) add up to 1. Suppose the patient is healthy and given a test - the test can result in a true negative outcome or a false positive outcome and these two probabilities (1-alpha and alpha, respectively) add up to one. Each set of probabilities is conditioned on the health status of the patient.

Answer (score 0):

I see some confusion here, maybe I can help :

1. A true positive is something your method identifies as a positive, and actually is. If you run a HIV test and it's positive, and if the patient is sick, then it's a true positive.
2. A false positive is something your method identifies as a positive, but is not. In the same example, your patient is not sick but the test is positive.